# Как перевести "regretted loss" с английского на русский?

Tags: терминология, перевод

Решил начать переводить статьи по HR-аналитике с английского на русский. Столкнулся с фразой "regretted loss", которая создает трудности для дальнейшего перевода. Думаю, что это означает "потеря наиболее перспективных сотрудников". А что думаете вы? Ссылку со статьей прилагаю.
https://www.analyticsinhr.com/blog/what-is-hr-analytics/

Comment: Я бы сказал "отток ценных сотрудников"

Comment: Потери, которые заставляют сожалеть. Это если влоб. Да и по сути тоже - ведь из увольняющихся или там переводящихся в другое подразделение кого-то жаль терять, а на чей-то уход покласть...